# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{n \to 
> \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}$$

Maybe we can believe with assurance that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}\approx\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}}.$$
Thus, we can obtain
$$\lim_{n \to 
\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}=\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}=\pi$$
This is true? If so, how to prove it rigorously?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}$ is not defined: the denominator is zero for $k=n$.

Comment: Yes ，but we can tear it into$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{n},$$ which is trivial.@MartinR

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the sum into two Riemann sums each of which converges to $\frac \pi 2$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n+1-k + k}{\sqrt{n+1-k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}\cdot \frac 1{n+1}$$
$$=\frac 1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{n+1-k}{k}} + \frac 1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{k}{n+1-k}}$$
$$= \underbrace{\frac 1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n+1}}-1}}_{\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac 1x-1}dx=\frac \pi2} +  \underbrace{\frac 1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n+1}}-1}}}_{\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac 1x -1}}dx=\frac \pi2}$$

Comment: Can we discard the term $k=n+1$?

Comment: @mengdie1982 : I am not sure what you mean by "discard".

Comment: Notice that $$\frac 1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n+1}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n+1}}-1}=\int_0^1 \cdots $$

Comment: Since you can change the function to be integrated at isolated points without changing the integral, you may set the missing term equal to zero.

Comment: Can we prove the original problem by the squeeze theorem？

Comment: I can imagine that there is a way by squeezing. But at the moment I don't have time to scrutinize into this. I may check this later.